# How to remove trailing slash from ZSH’s _files results?

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

I’m trying to create an autocompletion rule for a function that take an existing directory which should be located in a specific directory as an argument.

```
VENVS_PATH="${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.pyvenv"

compdef _venv_completion venv_activate
compdef '_files -W "${VENVS_PATH}" -/' venv_activate
```

This works, however when I’m typing `venv_activate` and hit TAB, Zsh suggest the right directories but with trailing slashes:

```
$ venv_activate
Dir1/  Dir2/
```

Is there a way to remove them **without** calling an external program?

Comment: Just being curious: Why do the trailing slashes bother you?

Comment: Did you consider using the options `AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH` and/or `ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS`? See _man zshall_ and grep for those. Having said this, _autoremoveslash_ is turned on by default in my zsh, i.e. the shell displays the slash after the directory, but when I type a space, the slash disappears again.

Comment: @user1934428 Neither enabling/disabling `AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH` or adding `/` to `ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS` seems to have effect on `_files`.

The function except a dir name without training slash, and also displaying the trailing slash is not really user friendly.